# google autocomplete region limitation continent and country

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-places-autocomplete

My api url like this
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$inputText&key=$mapKey&components=country:TR"
I want it to come as autocomplete in all of Europe and a few countries in the Middle East.
How should the request be?

Answer (score 0):

Currently Place Autocomplete has a limit of **5** countries in [the `components` filter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/autocomplete#components).

There is an open feature request to increase this limit: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/74602145.

Comment: Is there any way I can add a few countries along with Europe?

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can only use up to 5 individual countries. Please do comment on the public issue if you have ideas to improve on that, allowing "EU" for "Europe" could be good!

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it by taking the circle-shaped area and filtering the areas I do not want locally, for now.